# jQuery: Execute function as soon as a subset of images have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a slideshow that I need to initialize with jQuery. The initialization requires all slideshow images to be fully loaded, so that I can get their actual width and height. I can not change this part.

Consider the following layout:

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <img />
  <img />
  <img />
</div>
<img />
<img />
<img />
```

I need to initialize the slideshow as soon as the three images inside the *slideshow* container have been loaded. I can NOT wait until the rest of the images on the page have been loaded, as there might be thousands of images.

Any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Counting the load events on those 3 images would do the trick.

Comment: You can use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) though as the documentation page notes it has some known issues

Comment: The problem with using the *load* event is that sometimes jQuery is not able to trigger it on these images at all. My guess is that if the images are loaded from the cache, they are loaded even before jQuery fires the *ready* event on the document...

Comment: also count the existence of the `.complete` property on the images (for any cached ones). With a `setInterval` timer you could just poll until all have that set.

Comment: How would I go about combining the two? I have not been able to come up with a solution.

Comment: ...and back to comment #1... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Was able to come up with a solution, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you can wrap the checking/load behavior in a jQuery plugin and return a single promise like this:

```
$.fn.imagesLoaded = function () {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var count = this.length;
    this.each(function () {
        if (this.complete) {
            if (!--count) {
                def.resolve();
            }
        } else {
            $(this).load(function () {
                if (!--count) {
                    def.resolve();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return def.promise();
}
```

and then simply use like this:

```
$('.slideshow img').imagesLoaded().done(function () {
    alert("loaded");
});
```

Comment: Glad it helps. This is completely untested, as I wrote it straight into the answer, but it should do the trick. I:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using, quite a bit more complicated than I'd hoped:

```
// Prepare the slideshow as soon as all of its images have been loaded
var slideshowImages = $('.slideshow img');
var slideshowImagesLoadedCount = 0;

// Check how many images have already been loaded
slideshowImages.each(function() {
    if(this.complete) {
        slideshowImagesLoadedCount++;
    }
});

// If all the images have loaded already, prepare the slideshow
if(slideshowImagesLoadedCount === slideshowImages.length) {
    prepareSlideshow();
} else {

    // Otherwise wait until all images have been loaded
    slideshowImages.load(function() {
        slideshowImagesLoadedCount++;

        if(slideshowImagesLoadedCount === slideshowImages.length) {
            prepareSlideshow();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You could write a simple plugin, using deferreds/promises, to get this effect in a more readable way.